# Loading .csv file in solr with separator as special-character

Tags: solr, special-characters

Enviornment - java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS , solr-8.9.0

I am loading a csv file having separator Ǎ (decimal value- 461) in solr. For loading i have used following 2 ways.

```
1. curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/start13/update?commit=true&separator=Ǎ" --data-binary @/solr/python/special_character.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
2. curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/start13/update?commit=true&separator=\Ǎ" --data-binary @/solr/python/special_character.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

Both of the above command are leading to error as follows

```
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: URLDecoder: The query string contains a not-%-escaped byte &gt; 127 at position 23
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers$2.read(SolrRequestParsers.java:307)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parseFormDataContent(SolrRequestParsers.java:339)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(SolrRequestParsers.java:316)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(SolrRequestParsers.java:286)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.&lt;init&gt;(HttpSolrCall.java:194)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.getHttpSolrCall(SolrDispatchFilter.java:485)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:424)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)
```

curl loading command is running successfully for .csv file having separator as '|' . How to load csv file having special-character as a separator.

Comment: Have you tried to URL-encode your separator char? E.g `...&separator=%C7%8D` (not sure if this is the proper encode for your char). The [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVUpdateParameters) also hints you might need to escape, e.g `&separator=%C7%8D&escape=%5c` (%5c is the backslash char) but i can't access a Solr instance right now to test this. Give it a go.